# Highcharts pie labels outline mising using styled mode

Tags: css, highcharts

When using styled mode Pie Chart section labels no longer have the text outline.  This differs from non-styled mode, which does have it.  The specific css class that controls this is called "highcharts-text-outline".  No text element appears in styled mode (and thus, no outline to style).

Two examples:

Non-styled mode (notice the white outline on the text labels):
https://codepen.io/rpoconn/pen/QrGaxw

```
    Highcharts.chart('container', {

  title: {
    text: 'Highcharts pie chart'
  },

  xAxis: {
    categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
  },

  series: [{
    type: 'pie',
    allowPointSelect: true,
    keys: ['name', 'y', 'selected', 'sliced'],
    size: "100%",
    innerRadius: "60%",
    data: [
      ['Apples', 29.9, false],
      ['Pears', 71.5, false],
      ['Oranges', 106.4, false],
      ['Plums', 129.2, false],
      ['Bananas', 144.0, false],
      ['Peaches', 176.0, false],
      ['Prunes', 135.6, false],
      ['Avocados', 148.5, false]
    ],
    showInLegend: true
  }, {
    type: 'pie',
    innerRadius: "0%",
    size: "60%",
    allowPointSelect: true,
    keys: ['name', 'y', 'selected', 'sliced'],
    data: [
      ['Apples2', 2*29.9, false],
      ['Pears2', 2*71.5, false],
      ['Oranges2', 2*106.4, false],
      ['Plums2', 2*129.2, false],
      ['Bananas2', 144.0, false],
      ['Peaches2', 176.0, false],
      ['Prunes2', 3*135.6, false],
      ['Avocados2', 4*148.5, false]
    ],
    showInLegend: true
  }]
});
```

Styled mode (same code as above, but, uses the /js/highcharts + the highcharts.scss lib):
https://codepen.io/rpoconn/pen/mLOpLQ

Does anyone know a way around this?  Is this a bug?  Can I use highcharts-data-label-box::after here and hack one in?   Is there a cleaner way?   I'm using HC 6.1, and standard highcharts.scss styles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For codepen 1:

Add the following:

```
tspan {
  stroke: none;
}
```

or for the outline

```
tspan {
  stroke: white;
}
```

Codepen 2 requires the use of a work around using text shadow:

```
.highcharts-data-label text {
    fill: #333333;
    text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 white, 1px -1px 0 white, -1px 1px 0 white, 1px 1px 0 white;
}
```

That should do the job.